# Hyperopt installation on Windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, importerror

I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know how to install Hyperopt using anaconda on windows 10. I tried this [instruction](https://anaconda.org/jaikumarm/hyperopt) to install it as it shows below:

```
(C:\Users\Markazi.co\ Anaconda3) C:\Users\Markazi.co>conda install -c jaikumarm hyperopt=0.1
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - hyperopt 0.1*
You can search for packages on anaconda.org with
    anaconda search -t conda hyperopt
(C:\Users\Markazi.co\ Anaconda3) C:\Users\Markazi.co>conda install -c jaikumarm hyperopt
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: ..........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Markazi.co\Anaconda3:
#
hyperopt                  0.0.3.dev                py35_0    jaikumarm
(C:\Users\Markazi.co\ Anaconda3) C:\Users\Markazi.co>
```

Although it seems that the packages are installed, this error is reported:

```
from hyperopt import hp, fmin, tpe
ImportError: cannot import name 'hp'
```

Then, I tried to install it using python:

```
(C:\Users\Markazi.co\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Markazi.co>conda remove -c jaikumarm hyperopt
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: ..........
Package plan for package removal in environment C:\Users\Markazi.co\Anaconda3:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    pip-9.0.1                  |           py35_1         1.7 MB

The following packages will be REMOVED:
    hyperopt: 0.0.3.dev-py35_0 jaikumarm
The following packages will be UPDATED:
    pip:      8.1.2-py35_0               --> 9.0.1-py35_1
Proceed ([y]/n)? y
Fetching packages ...
pip-9.0.1-py35 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:01   1.05 MB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
(C:\Users\Markazi.co\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Markazi.co>conda update pip
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..........
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Markazi.co\Anaconda3:
#
pip                       9.0.1                    py35_1
(C:\Users\Markazi.co\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Markazi.co>pip install hyperopt
Collecting hyperopt
  Downloading hyperopt-0.1.tar.gz (98kB)
    100% |################################| 102kB 172kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\markazi.co\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hyperopt)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\markazi.co\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hyperopt)
Requirement already satisfied: nose in c:\users\markazi.co\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hyperopt)
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in c:\users\markazi.co\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hyperopt)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\markazi.co\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hyperopt)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in c:\users\markazi.co\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hyperopt)
Collecting future (from hyperopt)
  Downloading future-0.16.0.tar.gz (824kB)
    100% |################################| 829kB 107kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=3.4.0 in c:\users\markazi.co\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from networkx->hyperopt)
Building wheels for collected packages: hyperopt, future
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for hyperopt ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Markazi.co\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\4b\0f\9d\1166e48523d3bf7478800f250b0fceae31ac6a08b8a7cca820
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for future ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Markazi.co\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\c2\50\7c\0d83b4baac4f63ff7a765bd16390d2ab43c93587fac9d6017a
Successfully built hyperopt future
Installing collected packages: future, hyperopt
Successfully installed future-0.16.0 hyperopt-0.1
(C:\Users\Markazi.co\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Markazi.co>
```

Again, it is installed but the same error is reported:

```
from hyperopt import hyperopt, fmin, tpe
ImportError: cannot import name 'hyperopt'
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://anaconda.org/jaikumarm/hyperopt) you can do it via

> conda install -c jaikumarm hyperopt=0.1

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the pip command

```
pip install hyperopt
```